# how to get the system model (product name like :Proliant DL580 Gen9) with SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, server, server-configuration

I'm Looking for a way to find the system model like "Proliant DL580 Gen9",
but I can't found any way to gain this.

[System Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTEp3.png)

I try below query and used the "master.sys.xp_regread" procedure to get the server model name

```
DECLARE @ServerType VARCHAR(max)
EXEC master.sys.xp_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
                           @key = 'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS\0',
                           @value_name = 'SystemProductName',
                           @value = @ServerType OUTPUT;
SELECT @ServerType
```

which returns the `NULL` value!

Is there a way to get the system model like "Proliant DL580 Gen9"?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-sys-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I suggest you use PowerShell instead of T-SQL for this task: `(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

You can get the model using the query bellow:

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_regread 
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key = 'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS',
    @value_name = 'SystemProductName'
GO
```

The result should give you the equivalent information which you get by executing the wmic command

```
wmic computersystem get model
```

For anything that you are not sure, you can simply open the registry using the command regedit, find the value which you are looking for, and change the parameters in the query above

For example here are some common values which people need:

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_regread 
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key = 'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS',
    @value_name = 'SystemManufacturer'
GO
EXEC master.sys.xp_regread 
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key = 'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS',
    @value_name = 'SystemVersion'
GO
EXEC master.sys.xp_regread 
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key = 'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS',
    @value_name = 'SystemProductName'
GO

EXEC master.sys.xp_regread 
    @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key = 'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System',
    @value_name = 'SystemBiosVersion'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my question
Also I found another way to get this property.

```
DECLARE @SysInfo TABLE (Property NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @SysInfo (Property) 
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'systeminfo | findstr /C:"System Model"';
SELECT  (SELECT LTRIM(REPLACE(Property, 'System Model:', ''))       
    FROM @SysInfo WHERE Property LIKE '%System Model%');
```

Best Regards

Comment: You are most welcome`:)`. Remember that (as point in the Doc) xp_cmdshell is an extended stored which "spawns a Windows command shell and passes in a string for execution". In other words this is not a query but a windows command. You can also use the wmic command this way. By default xp_cmdshell is disabled and you will need to reconfigure the server in order to use it, which might considered as opening a security windows. xp_regread is also extended stored, but it does not require to open any security configuration if the user have the right permissions, but XP_Regread is undocumented

Comment: thank you for hint ;) 
I couldn't get the system model and I had to use this